# I can't connect to my MongoDB, which I run in docker compose

Tags: mongodb, docker, go, docker-compose

Here is my docker compose:

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  app:
    container_name: app
    build:
      context: ./..
      dockerfile: deployments/Dockerfile
    env_file:
      - ../configs/config.env
    ports:
      - ${APP_PORT:-8080}:8080
    networks:
      - network
    restart: always

  db:
    image: mongo:latest
    container_name: mongodb
    restart: always
    env_file:
      - ../configs/config.env
    ports:
      - ${MONGODB_PORT:-27017}:27017
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: ${MONGODB_ROOT_USER:-admin}
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MONGODB_ROOT_PASSWORD:-admin}
    volumes:
      - ../assets/mongo-init.sh:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/mongo-init.sh


  adminer:
    image: adminer
    container_name: db-adminer
    restart: always
    ports:
      - ${ADMINER_PORT:-17860}:8080
    networks:
      - network
    depends_on:
      - db

networks:
  network:
    driver: bridge
```

Here is my mongo-init.sh file:

```
use newdb

db.createUser(
        {
            user: admin,
            pwd: admin,
            roles: [
                {
                    role: "readWrite",
                    db: "newdb"
                }
            ]
        }
);
```

Here I am trying to connect to the database, but I get the following error: **topology is connected or connecting**

```
client, err := mongo.Connect(ctx, options.Client().ApplyURI(fmt.Sprintf("mongodb://%s:%s@%s:%s",
        cfg.DbUsername, cfg.DbPassword, cfg.DbHost, cfg.DbPort)))
```

I don't understand what the error might be, since everything is fine in the env file and all the variables match the authentication parameters in mongo

Comment: The error seems to suggest that you are calling `mongo.Connect` multiple times. If you are already connected, any further calls will return this error. So it seems to be a software issue not a setup/deployment issue. https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver/blob/master/x/mongo/driver/topology/topology.go#L42

Comment: @caveman I checked what you wrote, but it did not solve the problem, since at this point I am connecting to mongo for the first time

Comment: As far as I can see this is the only location where this error is returned. https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver/blob/2fa2b7c7575618b6e47a7f9e78df3e8a831b540a/x/mongo/driver/topology/topology.go#L148. I recommend you setup [delve](https://github.com/go-delve/delve) or gdb and set some breakpoints to diagnose why you might fall into this statement

Comment: You did not mention the network for Mongo DB. I believe it will use the default network for it and other containers are in a different network that's the reason your app is not able to connect to Mongo DB.

Comment: Please check if all the containers are in the same network.

Answer (score 0):

check this out:

```
services:
  productinfo:
    container_name: product_cntnr
    build: ./api-productinfo-service
    image: arc1999/api-productinfo-service
    ports:
      - '8090:8090'
    depends_on:
      db:
        condition: service_healthy
    links:
      - db
  scraping:
    build: ./api-scraping-service
    image: arc1999/api-scraping-service
    ports:
      - '8080:8080'
    depends_on:
      db:
        condition: service_healthy
    links:
      - db
  db:
    image: mongo:latest
    container_name: mongo_db
#    environment:
#      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
#      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: rootpassword
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    volumes:
      - mongodb_data_container:/data/db
    healthcheck:
      test: echo 'db.runCommand("ping").ok'
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
volumes:
  mongodb_data_container:
```

```
func InitDb() {
    host := "mongodb://mongo_db:27017" 
    rb := bson.NewRegistryBuilder()
    rb.RegisterTypeMapEntry(bsontype.EmbeddedDocument, reflect.TypeOf(bson.M{}))

    clientOptions := options.Client().ApplyURI(host).SetRegistry(rb.Build())

    // Connect to MongoDB
    client, err := mongo.Connect(context.TODO(), clientOptions)

    if err != nil {
        log.Panicln(err)
    }
    err = client.Ping(context.TODO(), nil)
    if err != nil {

        log.Panicln(err)
    }
    db = client.Database(os.Getenv("MONGO_DB_NAME"))
    fmt.Println("Connected to MongoDB!")
}
```